# how to vertically align div in a form container

Tags: html, css

http://kenzshop.com/test/contact/index.php

Click on CONTACT US button to view form.

I am sure this is an extremely simple fix, I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I have moved the div to several different areas, and played with the CSS, and can't seem to get it to where I want it, without it having blank space below the form.

I have the "Information" text showing underneath the form aligned right properly, but it shouldn't be below the form container.

It is aligned right in the correct position. I just need it to sit within the form container (fg_formContainer)

Thanks for any help.
Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#fg_container_header
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#fg_form_InnerContainer
{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Linus, Not really sure why the header had anything to do with that, but it works. So Thanks!